# Generic method for WPF Window in a Separate Thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am using the bellow code for showing WPF window in seperate thread, which is working find however I have a lot of windows so this code is kind of repetitive. Could someone suggest on how to make it generic by passing Windows etc)? Thx

```
  // Create a thread
Thread newWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart( () =>
{
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(
        new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher));

    Window1 tempWindow = new Window1();
    tempWindow.Closed += (s,e) => Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background);

    tempWindow.Show();

    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
}));

newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;

newWindowThread.Start();
```

Comment: In WPF there's no need to create a new Thread for UI parts. All the UI have to run on a single UI Thread. There's no benefit at creating a new thread for each new window... Even if you have 42 windows, a single UI Thread can manage to redraw the correctly.

Comment: Is the type of the Window class the only thing that varies? If so, create a generic constraint `where T : Window, new()`.  Then you can write `new T()` to create the window.

Comment: @Sharped: There is a reason for showing them in different thread.

Comment: I guess, but which one ?

Comment: WPF window is created on top of MS Outlook, and If I won;t put it in separate thread it will not behave appropriate

Comment: That's a good reason :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a possible refactoring could be :

```
public static class WindowHelper
{
    public static void CreateWindow<TWindow>(Action onClose = null)
        where TWindow : Window, new()
    {
        // Create a thread
        Thread newWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(
                new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(
                    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher));
            TWindow tempWindow = new TWindow();
            tempWindow.Closed += (s, e) => 
               { 
                  if(onClose != null)
                      onClose();
                  Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Backgroud);
               }; 
            tempWindow.Show();
            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
        }));

        newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
        newWindowThread.Start();
    }
}
```

And you can call this method like :

```
WindowHelper.CreateWindow<Window1>();
```

or

```
WindowHelper.CreateWindow<Window1>(() => Console.WriteLine("Closed"));
```

Comment: really nice:) thx... Is there any way of sending On Closed event something back (e.g.) to the main thread?

Comment: Hmm,, I see that you are passing something to the thread... but I need actually to receive from the thread... e.g. Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke in tempWindow.Closed event... however this is not working

Comment: I'm passing a delegate (`Action`) to the anonymous `Closed` event handler. By this way, when the window is closed, the delegate is called. You can transform this example by passing an `Action<String>`, and call `onClose("myData");` to retrieve the things you want in the delegate back to the caller.